# When does spark master show that memory is in use and çores are in use?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am running spark on YARN.  In the yarn UI at port `8088` I can see that there is a jobclearly running, and when I click on `ApplicationMaster` on the right hand side, it shows that the job is progressing in spark.

When I go to the port `18080` for the spark master however, I see that the "Memory in use" is 0, the "Cores in use" is 0, and the "Applications: 0 Running".

How do I get spark master to acknowledge that I am running an application and using cores and memory?  The job is progressing obviously because I can see things being written to disk, but why is spark master not up-to-date on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Master is a component of Spark Standalone. Yarn and Spark Standalone are both cluster managers. You should just use either one. If you submit an application to Yarn, you won't be able to see it on Spark Master. The cluster resource is managed by Yarn, not Spark Master, in this case.